# Is there a way to highlight text matching a regular expression in Chrome even upon page redirection?

Tags: google-chrome, regex

Is there a way to highlight all words that are written in ALL CAPS when I load certain pages in Chrome?

Ideally, the solution would work for the current page, and when I click the form button, it needs to work on the subsequent pages automatically as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Download the extension [Here](http://memelordsunited.co.uk/download). Installation instructions are the same as the instructions found [here](http://memelordsunited.co.uk/memelordslenny)

This extension simply highlights all the capital words on a page

### Rest of answer

I assume you mean for this to be user side, right?

I personally would create a simple Chrome extension for this task, probably because I like doing things the long way round. That and I'm pretty sure there isn't a function in Chrome allowing this (forgive me if I am wrong).

Chrome extensions are extremely easy to to make, so don't feel threatened. Here's a little thing I just whipped up that highlights all words in caps on a page, with an on/off toggle.

### How it will work

This little Chrome extension will run silently in the background of all pages and highlight every word that is over two letters long and in capitals with a yellow background. It will work on every page, and can be disabled by using the "enable/disable" feature in Chrome's extensions manager. It uses a very basic Jquery script to work.

### Step one

You need to create a folder somewhere on your hard drive for all the files. I called it "capshighlighter"

### Step Two

Add a few files to this folder using Notepad. Open Notepad, click "save as" on a blank document, and save it as `manifest.json`.

Create another file called `jquery.js` and another called `myscript.js`

### Step three

Add the following to `manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Capslight",
    "description": "Highlight capital words",
    "version": "1.0",
"content_scripts": 
    [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
            "js":["jquery.js", "myscript.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]

}
```

### Optional

To allow this script to run only on certain pages, change the value of `matches` in the maifest.json file. Separate each page by a comma. For example, if you wanted the script only to run on Stackoverflow, Superuser and Google, you'd do:

```
"matches": ["http://www.stackoverflow.com/*","http://www.superuser.com/*","https://google.co.uk/*"],
```

#### Note

Make sure you use the correct "http" or "https" for the URLs you want it to work on. A better way of doing this would be to put the URL in as a "http" link AND a "https" link. Don't forget the `*` after the trailing slash too. If this gets too complicated, it'd be best just to use the original `manifest.json` file I typed out above and just switch off the extension when you don't need it.

#### Next

Add Jquery 2.1 to `jquery.js`. To do this, you can simply copy and paste everything from [This link](http://byonex.co.uk/scripts/jquery.js)

#### Finally

Add the following to `myscript.js`

```
$('body').each(function(){
    var pattern = /([A-Z]{3,})/g;
    var before = '<span style="background: yellow;">';
    var after = '</span>';
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(pattern, before+"$1"+after));
});
```

### Step four - adding to Chrome

You have successfully made a working extension (never thought you'd be doing that today, I bet). Now you simply have to add it to Chrome. To do this, go to `chrome://extensions` and tick the "developer mode" box. Then click "load unpacked extension" and choose the folder where these three files are kept. The extension will get to work the moment you load a page. To disable to extension, simply untick the box in the `chrome://extensions` page.

I sure hope this is what you wanted. Regardless, it was a fun thing to make ;)

Comment: Very nice. Works great for the general text, but unfortunately you end up with the HTML code in the form fields. I guess the perfect solution would somehow manipulate Chrome and not the HTML on the page.

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this extension very useful for regex hightlighting and log analyzing:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rex-regex-highlight-or-co/eejlhekkafpkffbhpidchepheodkgnib

You can configure it to highlight text of your choise on pages and it will automatically apply this configuration on selected domains.

[Example of configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imT3w.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).